# Flow with REST Api to create SharePoint sites shows success but not creating sites

Tags: json, rest, sharepoint

I'm following this video to enable self service SharePoint site creation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQqb_i-Vgew . After a bit of work the Flow is showing that it's running successfully but it's not creating a site.

The output in the Flow shows this:

```
<d:SiteId></d:SiteId><d:SiteStatus m:type="Edm.Int32">3</d:SiteStatus><d:SiteUrl></d:SiteUrl></d:Create>
```

Site status 3 isn't giving me a lot to go on.

I've hunted for a solution to this and there aren't any sites in the deleted folder with the same name.

Here's the Body of the HTML action:

```
{
  "request": {
    "Title": "Communication Site 1",
    "Url": "http://xxx/sites/@{item()?['Title']}",
    "Lcid": 1033,
    "ShareByEmailEnabled": false,
    "Classification": "Low Business Impact",
    "Description": "A test site",
    "WebTemplate": "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0",
    "SiteDesignId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "Owner": "@{item()?['']?['']}",
    "WebTemplateExtensionId": "f6cc5403-0d63-442e-96c0-285923709ffc"
  }
}
```

I've tried hardcoding the Owner and changing the `webtempateextensionID` but same outcome.

Any suggestions or alternatives welcome!

Comment: See if any of these links help - 
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095671/api-spsitemanager-create-site-creation-failing-with-sitestatus-3

And: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/SharePoint-API-call-to-create-site-not-working/td-p/709400

And: https://www.koskila.net/new-pnpsite-fails-with-sitestatus3/